# It is possible to use ScaleType CENTER_CROP but without centering the image vertically? (showing the top of the image)

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, imageview, scale

I'm displaying a imageview with a bitmap. The imageview initially shows some blank spaces in left and right of the bitmap, so i used CENTER_CROP to solve that. The problem is that now the bitmap is centered vertically and the top of the image can't be visible, and i dont want that. I want that the image top must be displayed, i don't care about the bottom.

It is possible to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the paddingTop to image.I hope by setting paddingTop to the image view  you can push the top of the content downward. Sometimes at bottom it will miss something but still you will be able to see the top of the image.